# Тире или двоеточие в предложениях?

Tags: грамматика, тире, двоеточие, приложение, тире-или-двоеточие

Скажите, в этих случаях лучше поставить двоеточие или тире?

1. Этот курс ориентирован на нетехнических специалистов – на, можно сказать, гуманитариев, для которых часто вход в профессию анализа данных затруднен.
2. Сайт является самостоятельной разработкой факультета, он сделан на платформе GitHub – там же, где хостятся крупнейшие программные опенсорсные проекты.

Answer (score 1):

В предложении под номером 1 посоветую изменить порядок слов на такой:
*Этот курс ориентирован на нетехнических специалистов. Можно сказать, на гуманитариев, для которых часто вход в профессию анализа данных затруднен.*
В предложении под номером 2 всё идеально.